# Insert failed on parent table with new column

Tags: sql, postgresql, partitioning

I've got a main table (payment) and some partitioned tables (payment_AAAA_MM). I obtain these tables with a store function like this one:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION partitioning_payment()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
 DECLARE
 numero integer;
 month float;
 year float;
 monthp float;
 yearp float;
 months text;
 monthps text;
 
 BEGIN
 month=DATE_PART('month',NEW.REQUEST_TS);
 year=DATE_PART('year',NEW.REQUEST_TS);
 monthp=month;
 yearp=year;
 months=month;
 monthps=monthp;
 IF month = 12 THEN
 yearp=yearp+1;
 monthp=1;
 ELSE
 monthp=monthp+1;
 END IF;
 monthps=monthp;
 IF(length(month::text)=1) THEN
 months=month::text;
 months='0' || months;
 END IF;
 IF(length(monthp::text)=1) THEN
 monthps=monthp::text;
 monthps='0' || monthps;
 END IF;
 EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM PG_TABLES WHERE SCHEMANAME=''public'' AND TABLENAME=''payment_' || year || '_' || months || '''' INTO numero;
 IF numero=0 THEN
 EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE payment_' || year || '_' || months || '(CHECK ( REQUEST_TS >= ''' || year || '-' || months || '-01 00:00:00'' and REQUEST_TS <  ''' || yearp || '-' || monthps || '-01 00:00:00'' )) inherits (payment)';
 END IF;
 
 EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO payment_' || year || '_' || months || ' (id,id_request,REQUEST_TS,response)
 VALUES (
 '''||NEW.ID||''',
 '''||NEW.ID_REQUEST||''',
 '''||NEW.REQUEST_TS||''',
 '''||NEW.RESPONSE||'''
 )';
 RETURN null; END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

CREATE TRIGGER partitioning_payment
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON payment
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE partitioning_payment();
```

Everything is working correctly.

Now, I have to add to parent table a column (is_test integer type). I've added column in parent table, and modify function in this way

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION partitioning_payment()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
 DECLARE
 numero integer;
 month float;
 year float;
 monthp float;
 yearp float;
 months text;
 monthps text;
 
 BEGIN
 month=DATE_PART('month',NEW.REQUEST_TS);
 year=DATE_PART('year',NEW.REQUEST_TS);
 monthp=month;
 yearp=year;
 months=month;
 monthps=monthp;
 IF month = 12 THEN
 yearp=yearp+1;
 monthp=1;
 ELSE
 monthp=monthp+1;
 END IF;
 monthps=monthp;
 IF(length(month::text)=1) THEN
 months=month::text;
 months='0' || months;
 END IF;
 IF(length(monthp::text)=1) THEN
 monthps=monthp::text;
 monthps='0' || monthps;
 END IF;
 EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM PG_TABLES WHERE SCHEMANAME=''public'' AND TABLENAME=''payment_' || year || '_' || months || '''' INTO numero;
 IF numero=0 THEN
 EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE payment_' || year || '_' || months || '(CHECK ( REQUEST_TS >= ''' || year || '-' || months || '-01 00:00:00'' and REQUEST_TS <  ''' || yearp || '-' || monthps || '-01 00:00:00'' )) inherits (payment)';
 END IF;
 
 EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO payment_' || year || '_' || months || ' (id,id_request,REQUEST_TS,response,is_test)
 VALUES (
 '''||NEW.ID||''',
 '''||NEW.ID_REQUEST||''',
 '''||NEW.REQUEST_TS||''',
 '''||NEW.RESPONSE||''',
 '||NEW.IS_TEST||'
 )';
 RETURN null; END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

However, now I've got this situation:

- In parent table and partitioned table `is_test` is present
- If I make an insert on partitioned table, I've got new row
- if I make an insert on parent table, nothing happens

So, how can I add a new column correctly and permit me to do an insert on the parent table?

Comment: Unrelated but, the "formatting" of the `months` content can be simplified to: `months := to_char(NEW.REQUEST_TS, 'mm');`, i.e. you can extract that in a formatted way directly from the date (or timestamp) value without copying it back and forth between three variables.

Comment: I'll do it later, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...shame on me. I've updated procedure, but you have to drop and recreate trigger on payment table